# SQL statement to select all rows from previous day with time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need to select rows from the previous day but before 08:00 am.

```
(date >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
       AND CONVERT(varchar, date,108) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '08:00:00')
```

return rows of from the previous day and before 08:00 am.

Comment: You should tag the question with the database you are using, which is presumably SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
where date >= dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate())) and
      date < dateadd(hour, -16, convert(date, getdate()))
```

This query is structured so it can make use of indexes.

You can also phrase this as:

```
where convert(date, [date]) = dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate()) and
      convert(time, [date]) <= '08:00:00'
```

This should also use indexes, because conversion to a date is perhaps the only function that does not prevent the use of an index.

Comment: thanks, they both worked, but I like the second version best. final code looks like this: 

((convert(date, [date]) = dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate())) and
convert(time, [date]) <= '08:00:00'))

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. This does a `BETWEEN` check on the beginning of the day yesterday and the beginning of the day yesterday + 8 hours:

```
date BETWEEN dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0) 
         AND dateadd(hour, 8, dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0))
```